# Google Big query different result based on same date filter

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

> Edit 1: so the issue is '<=' is acting as '<' in google query which is
> strange. But '>=' acts normally. Any idea why this is happening?

Goal: to get data for May 2019.

Info about database here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/

Query 1 uses **timestamp > '2019-04-30' AND timestamp < '2019-06-01'**

```
SELECT file.project AS package, COUNT(file.project) AS installs, FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m', timestamp) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads` 
WHERE timestamp > '2019-04-30' AND timestamp < '2019-06-01'
GROUP BY month, package;
```

[image]

Query 2 uses **timestamp >= '2019-05-01' AND timestamp <= '2019-05-31'**

```
SELECT file.project AS package, COUNT(file.project) AS installs, FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m', timestamp) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads` 
WHERE timestamp >= '2019-05-01' AND timestamp <= '2019-05-31'
GROUP BY month, package;
```

[image]

Both query one and two should scan same amount of data - May 2019 but both query gives different results and scans different amount of data as you can see in attached images.

Which one is correct and why both are not matching?

Comment: Why don't you just try out? Extend the where clause in one of the two queries by NOT IN (...) and put the other query as subquery, this will list those entries that are found by one query, but not by the other. If the affected data is too much, just reduce the time range to one week or one day only in your queries.

Comment: @JonasMetzler did that and issue is '<=' is acting as '<' in google query which is strange. But '>=' acts normally. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing `timestamp` with a `date` literal. When a `date` literal is implicitly cast as `timestamp`, it will have '00:00:00' time.

##### Query 1 uses timestamp > '2019-04-30' AND timestamp < '2019-06-01'

This is same as

```sql
timestamp > '2019-04-30 00:00:00 UTC' AND timestamp < '2019-06-01 00:00:00 UTC'
```

which includes data between `2019-04-30 00:00:01 UTC` and `2019-04-30 23:59:59 UTC`.

##### Query 2 uses timestamp >= '2019-05-01' AND timestamp <= '2019-05-31'

same as

```sql
timestamp >= '2019-05-01 00:00:00 UTC' AND timestamp <= '2019-05-31 00:00:00 UTC'
```

in this case, you're missing data between `2019-05-31 00:00:01 UTC` and `2019-05-31 23:59:59 UTC` which is incorrect.

##### Correct Condition

You might want to use:

```sql
timestamp >= '2019-05-01' AND timestamp < '2019-06-01'
```

Note that since `BEWEEN` condition is inclusive, following conditions will not be what you want also.

```sql
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN  '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' --> this will ignore data on last day of May except '2019-05-31 00:00:00 UTC'.
or
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN  '2019-05-01' AND '2019-06-01' --> this will include '2019-06-01 00:00:00 UTC' data like below screenshot.
```

[image]

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp) month, COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads`
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN  '2019-05-01' AND '2019-06-01' -- scan 22.57 GB
 GROUP BY 1
```

(update)

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM timestamp) day, COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads`
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2019-05-29' AND '2019-05-31'
 GROUP BY 1
;

output:
+-----+-----+-----------+
| Row | day |    cnt    |
+-----+-----+-----------+
|   1 |  30 | 116744449 |
|   2 |  29 | 120865824 |
|   3 |  31 |      1027 |  -- should be 112116613
+-----+-----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The two filters are different, you can simply check the difference in the result by the below script.

###### Differences

```
SELECT timestamp, FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m', timestamp) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads` 
WHERE
    timestamp > '2019-04-30' AND timestamp < '2019-06-01'
    AND NOT (timestamp >= '2019-05-01' AND timestamp <= '2019-05-31')
;
```

###### Results

[image]

###### Personal Preference

```
SELECT file.project AS package, COUNT(file.project) AS installs, FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m', timestamp) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.pypi.file_downloads`
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31'
```

p.s. As you can check out in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax), the ordering of the standard SQL is below. The `filter` of `WHERE` happens before the `SELECT`, thus you might want to store the result of the `SELECT` statement and do the filtering to filter by **date**, not **datetime**.

> `FROM` -> `WHERE` -> `GROUP BY` -> `HAVING` -> ...

Comment: `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31'` will discard data on last day of May.

Comment: I believe it won't. Please check the official [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators?hl=en). `The result of "X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "Y <= X AND X <= Z"`

Comment: I just wanted to mention that since `timestamp` column is not a `DATE` type but a `TIMESTAMP` type in this problem, so if  `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31'` condition applies to the problem, it will get a wrong answer and most of data on 5/31 will be discarded.  Kindly check my updated answer .

Comment: Sorry. I actually missed that part. Thanks for pointing it out.